# Rails map custom columns of excel file to db columns

Tags: csv, ruby-on-rails-5, roo

I am using `Roo` to parse my CSV files for import. Everything works perfectly, but sometimes the end users will change the column headers of the excel file. For example, if the db column is `first_name` the users might change the header in the excel file to `firstname`. In such a casse, it is easy to use `alias_attribute` method to map a header to the correct db column name.

However, how can I handle a situation where the column header in the excel is very long? For example, something like `the user's first name and last name` The `alias_attribute` method cannot be used here:

```
alias_attribute :first_name, :the user's first name and last name
```

How would you parse verbose or long column headers in a csv file to map to a normal db column name?

Here is my implementation of `roo`:

```
def load_imported_users
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet
    header = spreadsheet.row(2)
    (3..spreadsheet.last_row).map do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      user = User.find_by_national_id(row["national_id"]) || User.new

      user.attributes = row.to_hash
      user
    end
  end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just use the `string` like `alias_attribute "first_name", "the user's first and last name"`? Symbol is kind of `string` without an extra baggage anyways :)

Comment: Really great! How would I use the same approach when mapping to associations columns? Something like ```alias_attribute "country_name", "country of origin" ``` but this time around, instead of saving the name of the country, you convert it to ```country_id``` column in the table?